# How to set two way binding data in dropdown in angular 6?

Tags: angular6, bind, dropdown

I have a data like this.

```
[
   {
       "user_id": 1,
       "name": "John"   
   },
   {
       "user_id": 2,
       "name": "Doe"   
   },
   ...
]
```

In app, I have set two dropdown for show only user_id and name respectively.

For user id I have used simple `select` and `option`.

For `name` I have used `ngx-select-dropdown`.

Now I have to make two way binding, when I select `Doe` then id dropdown `2` will automatically bind. Same way if I choose id `1` then `John` will autimatically select.

I have a design like below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue with the help of `reactive form group`. It provides me value easily and I have set it's form value with the help of `patchValue()` feature. And it works fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

To dynamically generate a drop-down list, based on the data above, create a model.

**User-model.ts**

```
export class UserModel {
    user_id: number;
    name: string; }
```

In the **component**, it would look something like this

```
import { UserModel } from '../app/model/user-model';

curr_name: string = '';
curr_user_id: number = null;
users: UserModel[] = 
[
  {
    "user_id": 1,
    "name": "John"
  },
  {
    "user_id": 2,
    "name": "Doe"
}];

getName(id: any): void {
  if (id !== 'SELECT') { // SELECT is used for default here
    this.curr_name = this.users.find(x => x.user_id == id).name;
  }
}

getUserId(name: any): void {
  if (name !== 'SELECT') {
    this.curr_user_id = this.users.find(x => x.name == name).user_id;
  }
}
```

And lastly, based on the your design, the **HTML** code would essentially look like

```
<select (change)="getName($event.target.value)">
  <option>SELECT</option>
  <option *ngFor="let user of users" [ngValue]="user.user_id" 
      [selected]="user.user_id === curr_user_id">
    {{user.user_id}}
  </option>
</select>

<select (change)="getUserId($event.target.value)">
  <option> SELECT</option>
  <option *ngFor="let user of users" [ngValue]="user.name" 
     [selected]="user.name === curr_name">
   {{user.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

*Though since you are updating both drop-downs regardless why not create only one dropdown and have the `user-id` and `name` in a list format so you wouldn't need to keep updating each other.*

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I cann't set both in one due to client don't need in one. :)

Comment: I have already look this option but  still I'm find other way to do this without create a seprate model  for that. If I cann't get any other way then I'll try by this way.

Comment: Is is work with `ngx-select-dropdown` ? As I mention in my question , for name I have used another npm module.